# Q. How can I get SUSE repositories from update.suse.com in artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

It is needed to add repositories from SLES (updates.suse.com) as a remote repository to artifactory. I guess this would be done via "RPM" remote repository, but after entering the link (including token) there always be a 403. Would suspect that the problem is that the link should be accessed as a yum repo and the metadata should been read first.

How can I get this working?